# Implementing WPF AllowTransparency for a UserControl in an alternative assembly/library

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, mvvm, assemblies

I have a user control which I have moved into a central assembly named '**MVVMHelpersLibrary**' to help DRY out my code, as I want to use it across a couple of different applications.

This user control is simply just a border with content that I use to override my tool tips with in the main application, I've made it a border for the round edges.

In the main WPF application, with the parent window set to:

```
   WindowStyle="None"
```

and

```
   AllowsTransparency="True"
```

When the XAML is defined and used within the same main application assembly it displays the transparent border corners just fine.

But when the definition is in the **'MVVMHelpersLibrary'** library and it is used as a referenced control it displays a white background beneath the control, even though I set it to null.

The above properties seems to be unique for a Window, so I have tried creating a Window in the **MVVMHelpersLibrary** and set the properties as above, but same issue.

There also doesn't appear to be anyway the UserControl can inherit the transparency property itself that I can find, and I cannot make the UserControl into a window as that doesn't work with embedding it as a tool tip in the main application.

The UserControl is deriving from another BaseView class that derives from a UserControl just to add a few more properties and Change Notification, but it behaves the same just directly inheriting from UserControl.

---

**EDIT: With my code - Taken out obvious and irrelevant stuff for shortness**

**The Tooltip UserControl:**

```
   <views:BaseUserControl x:Class="MVVMHelpersLibrary.Views.FunkyToolTipView"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MVVMHelpersLibrary.Views">
<views:BaseUserControl.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="metallicBorder" EndPoint="0.998,0.5" StartPoint="0.025,0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF595959" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.7"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF303030" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource metallicBorder}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="toolTipHeading" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="toolTipContent" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource toolTipHeading}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    </Style>
</views:BaseUserControl.Resources>
<Border>
    <StackPanel Width="Auto">
        <TextBlock x:Name="HeadingValue" Text="{Binding Heading}" Style="{StaticResource toolTipHeading}" Width="Auto"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="BodyValue" Text="{Binding Body}" Style="{StaticResource toolTipContent}" Width="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="270"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

The control uses 2x Dependency properties so I can easily inject the Heading and Body elements into the control and have them formatted appropriately, such as:

```
    <TextBox Text="Time" >
          <TextBox.ToolTip>
                  <MVVMViews:FunkyToolTipView Heading="Batch Time" Body="The amount of time to run a batch scan for" />
           </TextBox.ToolTip>
     </TextBox>
```

---

Could you please suggest a solution where I can retain these dependency properties or at least be able to easily define the Body and Heading properties of the tooltip?

Comment: We need more code... or the project to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare a `UserControl` to define a custom `ToolTip`. You can do that simply in a `Style`. Try something like this instead:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" 
                    Background="White" Padding="5">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ToolTip.Content}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...

```
<Grid Background="Red" ToolTip="I'm a ToolTip with a Border" />
```

[image]

Just remember that when using WPF, there are many things that you can try *before* you need to declare a custom `UserControl` or `CustomControl`. Please read through the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for further information on what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is possible, I just forgot to export another general style that gets rid of the ugly default background:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```